# Export stock of products with attributes in Prestashop

Tags: mysql, prestashop

In my shop the Product A has different attributes, let them be: 
White (12pcs left), Black (10 left) and Red (6 left) 
I have managed to export into csv all products with their categories and quantities and attributes, but I would like the table to look as follows: 
Product A / White / 12 
Product A / Black / 10 
Product A / Red / 6 
Product B / Size S / 5 
Product B / Size M / 6

So all the quantities available for each combination of the product.
My query now is as follows:

```html
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    p.id_category_default,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cl.name) SEPARATOR ";") as categories,
    pa.reference,
    pl.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(pal.name) SEPARATOR "; ") as combination, 
    p.price, 
    pq.quantity
FROM 7_ps_product p 
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product) 
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_stock_available pq ON (p.id_product = pq.id_product AND pa.id_product_attribute = pq.id_product_attribute) 
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product) 
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_attribute_lang pal ON (pac.id_attribute = pal.id_attribute)
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_category_product cp ON (p.id_product = cp.id_product)
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_category_lang cl ON (cp.id_category = cl.id_category)
LEFT JOIN 7_ps_category c ON (cp.id_category = c.id_category)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1 
AND pal.id_lang = 1 
GROUP BY pa.reference
ORDER BY p.id_product, pac.id_attribute
```

Thanks for great contributions to help out people like me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your query like this, so to get the output you need

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(pl.name,' / ',pal.name,' / ', pq.quantity) AS required
FROM ps_product p 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product) 
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available pq ON (p.id_product = pq.id_product AND pa.id_product_attribute = pq.id_product_attribute) 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product) 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang pal ON (pac.id_attribute = pal.id_attribute)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product cp ON (p.id_product = cp.id_product)
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON (cp.id_category = cl.id_category)
LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (cp.id_category = c.id_category)
WHERE pl.id_lang = 1 
      AND pal.id_lang = 1 
GROUP BY p.id_product,pal.name
ORDER BY p.id_product, pac.id_attribute
```

I have changed the GROUP BY and SELECT fields. I think this is the answer you need.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! another quick question:
I have a new multistore, and I want to enable shared stock. If I enable it, all my quantities will dissapear. Is there a way to import these exported quantities back after I enable that option? Or do I have to do this manually? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think there is a CSV import in Prestashop in Admin module->Advanced Parameters->CSV Import. There is a import available for Combination. Check that if this  is what you need.

Comment: Available fields do not have attributes.. :/ -->
ID
Active (0/1)
Name
Categories (x,y,z...)
Price tax excluded or Price tax included
Tax rules ID
Wholesale price
On sale (0/1)
Discount amount
Discount percent
Discount from (yyyy-mm-dd)
Discount to (yyyy-mm-dd)
Reference #
Supplier reference #
Supplier
Manufacturer
EAN13
UPC
Ecotax
Width
Height
Depth
Weight
Quantity
Minimal quantity
Visibility
Additional shipping cost
Unit for the unit price
Unit price
Short description
Description
Tags (x,y,z...)
Meta title
Meta keywords
Meta description

Comment: URL rewritten
Text when in stock
Text when backorder allowed
Available for order (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Product availability date
Product creation date
Show price (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Image URLs (x,y,z...)
Delete existing images (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Feature (Name:Value:Position:Customized)
Available online only (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Condition
Customizable (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Uploadable files (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Text fields (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
Action when out of stock
ID / Name of shop 
Advanced Stock Management 
Depends on stock 
Warehouse

Comment: I think you have quantity field and you have product id too. Just create a combination csv and try. Else create a update query on your own and do an update in db directly